# I am using Jdk 14 in eclipse ,what will be maven java version POM.XML file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

my pom.xml file has java jdk1.8 ,I need to change it to jdk14.

Comment: If your project uses any specific version that is not in java-1.8 then you must change it to 14 in `pom.xml` else 1.8 is fine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add below property in your pom.xml .

```
<properties>
 <java.version>14</java.version>
</properties>
```

Also as per spring documentation you need to add below plugin to support java 14 preview features :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <release>14</release>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        <parameters>true</parameters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

ref link: https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/11/spring-tips-java-14-or-can-your-java-do-this

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
</properties>
```